# Calling a control event from another page

Tags: javascript

I have to pages

page # 1 has 2 control
textbox1  (this is an ID of a record)
textbox2  (this is the description of that record)
search button

textbox1 has an event change which updates textbox2 base on the data

page # 2 
this is call from the search button on page # 1
displays a list or records 
when user clicks on on  record it updates textbox1 on page # 1

```
window.opener.document.getElementById(toUpdate).value = ctl;
```

this works like a charm

now my problem is that the change event doesn't fire on page # 1

is there any way to force the change event on  page#1 from within page#2?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you set up your event (if you added a listener, or you're talking about the onchange event), you could either fire that event or call the onchange method like so:

document.getElementById('whateverelementyourelookingfor').onchange();

Answer (score 0):

Onchange doesn't trigger when you update via javascript. I would suggest using the Messaging API. It works in modern browsers (and IE8+).

From page #1, subscribe to the message:

```
function handleMessage(event) {
    //convert back to javascript object
    var updateObj = JSON.parse(event.data);
    //Get id from the data in the message
    var elem = document.getElementById(updateObj.toUpdate);
    //Set the value from the data in the message
    elem.value = updateObj.ctl;

    //perform change specific functions here.
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);
}
else {
    window.attachEvent("onmessage", handleMessage); // For IE8
}
```

From page #2, send the message to the window (instead of calling document.getElementById...):

```
//Post the message to the window. Second argument specifies the destination origin.
//Use "*" wildcard for anything
window.opener.postMessage(JSON.stringify({toUpdate: toUpdate, ctl: ctl}), "*");
```

I put together a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8LDh/1/) demonstrating this (even though the message is post from the same window).